# Firefox Widevine plugin crashes immediately after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: upgrade, firefox, 16.10

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.10 I am experiencing an immediate crash when trying to watch a video which uses the Widevine plugin.

- I am using Firefox 49
- Widevine works fine in Chrome
- I logged into guest mode and tried it there, but same problem occurs
- One of some crash reports I sent with Firefox: https://crash-stats.mozilla.com/report/index/088a0c5c-5509-423b-8347-6ed842161022#tab-details
- On a second PC with Firefox 49.0.2 and Ubuntu 16.04 everything worked fine, after upgrading to 16.10 I experience the same error

Hope someone can help

Comment: Since it works fine with Ubuntu 16.04 I created a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1638719

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Mozilla this is a problem with Firefox 49: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1315934

It is fixed with Firefox 50.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like to be a problem in firefox: In Firefox 50.0beta2 the plugin doesn't crash any more.

Comment: I just tried it on a second PC and there it works fine with Firefox 49.0.2 and Ubuntu 16.04 (also added that in the question)